# How to get a Java mutiline string using commons.cli

Tags: java, string, command-line

In my Java program, I use org.apache.commons.cli to parse my command line parameters, and want to get a mutiline String. When input `-s "Firstline\nSecondline\nthirdline`, seem to be unable to parse "\n", and cant split with "\n".How can I solve it?

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem a good way to pass multiline parameters via command line. May be you can achieve what you want another way?

Comment: @Mikhail Kopylov, Thank you for your reply! Though I implemented pass parameters via reading file, command line is also a worthy way in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\\n`, which of course is *not* a linefeed char, so a conversion will be needed. Also command line arg `@xxx.txt` is one way  to solve this. Or you redirect the standard input. In effect not using cli.